# Python - PySimpleGUI - Lock Relative Position of Windows (or Loading Animation Overlay)

Tags: python, pysimplegui, loading-animation

I've created an application to run a query and download some files from a database. I want to indicate the application is still running while the query resolves. Currently, the loading animation popup appears over the main window. However, when I minimize the main window, the popup remains. I want to popup to appear, disappear (minimize), and move relative to the main window.

I have not delved into the `Tkinter` documentation yet. I'm not sure how it would interact with `PySimpleGUI`. I'm hoping to just use `PySimpleGUI`, but I am open to other solutions.

I'd like to also use the modal functionality for it. The main window shouldn't support interaction while the download script is running.

[image]

[image]

```
import PySimpleGUI as psg

def download_thread():
    pass

psg.theme('GrayGrayGray')

layout = [
    [psg.Frame("Query",[
            [psg.Button('Open File'), psg.Button('Save File'), psg.Text('Untitled.sql', key = '-DOCNAME-')],
            [psg.Multiline(size = (120,30), key = '-TEXTBOX-', font='Consolas 12', no_scrollbar=True, expand_x=True)],
        ])],
    [psg.Column([[psg.Button('Download Files'),psg.Cancel()]], justification='right')]
    
]
window = psg.Window('File Download Tool', layout)

loading = False
while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout = 10)
    if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    if loading:
        psg.popup_animated(psg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF, time_between_frames=100)    
    else:
        psg.popup_animated(None)

    if event == 'Download Files':
        loading = True
        download_thread() # pretend this is threaded

    if event == 'Cancel':
        loading = False
```

Answer (score 1):

It won't work if you use the `popup_animated` provided by PySimpleGUI, try to design one by yourself if you need something different or special.

Following code demo the way by binding event `'<Configure>'` to popup window to move main window with same delta position, also with option `modal=True` of popup window to have this window be the only window a user can interact with until it is closed.

```py
from time import sleep
import threading
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def popup(main_window, window=None, duration=0, image=sg.DEFAULT_BASE64_LOADING_GIF):
    global x0, y0, x1, y1, user_event
    if window is None:
        layout = [[sg.Image(data=image, enable_events=True, key='-IMAGE-')]]
        x0, y0 = main_window.current_location(more_accurate=True)
        w0, h0 = main_window.current_size_accurate()
        window = sg.Window('Title', layout, no_titlebar=True, grab_anywhere=True,
            background_color='blue', element_padding=(0, 0), margins=(0, 0), finalize=True, modal=True)
        w1, h1 = window.current_size_accurate()
        x1, y1 = x0+(w0-w1)//2, y0+(h0-h1)//2
        window.move(x1, y1)
        window.refresh()
        window.bind("<Configure>", 'Configure')
    else:
        window['-IMAGE-'].update_animation(image, time_between_frames=duration)
    event, values = window.read(1)
    if event == 'Configure':
        if user_event:
            user_event = False
        else:
            x11, y11 = window.current_location(more_accurate=True)
            x00, y00 = main_window.current_location(more_accurate=True)
            if (x11, y11) != (x1, y1):
                x0, y0 = x0+x11-x1, y0+y11-y1
                main_window.move(x0, y0)
                x1, y1 = x11, y11
            elif (x00, y00) != (x0, y0):
                x1, y1 = x1+x00-x0, y1+y00-y0
                window.move(x1, y1)
                x0, y0 = x00, y00
                user_event = True
    return window

def download(window):
    sleep(5)
    window.write_event_value('Done', None)

sg.theme('GrayGrayGray')

layout = [
    [sg.Frame("Query",[
            [sg.Button('Open File'), sg.Button('Save File'), sg.Text('Untitled.sql', key = '-DOCNAME-')],
            [sg.Multiline(size = (120,30), key = '-TEXTBOX-', font='Consolas 12', no_scrollbar=True, expand_x=True)],
        ])],
    [sg.Column([[sg.Button('Download Files'),sg.Cancel()]], justification='right')]

]
window = sg.Window('File Download Tool', layout, finalize=True)
loading, popup_win, x1, y1, user_event = False, None, None, None, False
x0, y0 = window.current_location(more_accurate=True)

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout = 10)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break

    elif event == sg.TIMEOUT_EVENT and loading:
        popup_win = popup(window, popup_win, duration=100)

    elif event == 'Download Files':
        loading = True
        threading.Thread(target=download, args=(window, ), daemon=True).start()

    elif event == 'Done':
        popup_win.close()
        loading, popup_win = False, None

window.close()
```

Comment: Brilliant solution!

Comment: @Jason Thanks! Moving the loading popup works great!


1. I'm still seeing the popup when I switch to another window. I know I can set the `keep_on_top` parameter to false, but I was hoping to sync the behavior of the windows. Is there an event or something I can hook into?


2. If I move the main window, the popup does not move with it. I assume I can set up a `window.bind("<Configure>", 'Configure')` on the main window and `if event == 'Configure' and loading:` in the event loop with `popup_win.move()` but I'm having issues with the movement math.

Comment: There will be loop if you bind both window with `'<Configure>'` event to update another window. Code updated, but not do more tests.

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented the code and I'll let you know if I run into any issues.